# c# wpf animation completed не работает

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

Анимация расширения окна.
Как запустить метод после завершения анимации? Сама анимация работает, а Completed нет

```
bool expanded=false;

DoubleAnimation animExpand = new DoubleAnimation()
{
    To=300,
    Duration=new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(animtime)),
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
};

DoubleAnimation animCollapse = new DoubleAnimation()
{
    To = 120,
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(animtime)),
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
};
```

**1 вариант**

```
animExpand.Completed += (s, ev) =>
{
    expanded=true;
    label1.Text="expanded";
};

if (!expanded)
    BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, animExpand);
else 
    BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, animCollapse);
```

**2 вариант**

```
story = new Storyboard
{
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
    AutoReverse = false
};
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animExpand, new PropertyPath(HeightProperty));
story.Children.Add(animExpand);
story.Completed += (s, ev) =>
{
    expanded=true;
    label1.Text="expanded";
};
story.Begin(this);
```

Comment: Чем же XAML вам не угодил?

Comment: @aepot а как там Completed установить?

Comment: Подозреваю, что причина в RepeatBehavior.Forever. Оно делает анимацию неостанавливаемой , поэтому Completed никогда не срабатывает. Если быть точнее, оно сработает, только если запустить другую анимацию над тем же свойством, что приведёт к остановке прошлой анимации (или вручную стопорнуть).

Comment: А вообще, тут нужно поступать наоборот: изменение свойства Expanded должно запускать анимацию раскрытия/скрытия. А не так, как у вас. И такое делать лучше через VisualStateManager, ну или на основе триггеров на худой конец. Хотя, если прям стоит задача отследить окончание анимации... но не представляю зачем это нужно.